# What are the best way to enhance base class method from child class

Tags: typescript

Situation (In Typescript):

```
class BaseClass{
  List obj = new List();
  public Todo(){
      obj.Add("1");
      obj.Add("2");
      obj.Add("3");
  }
}
class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass{
  public Todo(){
      obj.Add("4");
      obj.Add("5");
      obj.Add("6");
  }
}
class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass{
  public Todo(){
      obj.Add("7");
      obj.Add("8");
      obj.Add("9");
  }
}
ChildClass1 child1 = new ChildClass1();
ChildClass2 child2 = new ChildClass2();
child1.Todo();
Child2.Todo();
```

Question is :
When I call Child classes method Todo I wanted the all list items added by BaseClass and also from ChildClass with one call of that method, How can I do that and what is the best way to do that?

One solution I can think of :
In the child class override method in child class and add base.Todo() in child class method itself like below.

```
 class ChildClass {
   public override Todo(){
       base.Todo();
       obj.Add("7");
       obj.Add("8");
       obj.Add("9");
   }
 }
```

Is this the best option for Typescript or any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that TypeScript is no JAVA. The Syntax above is not entirely applicable. You always only have one anonymous constructor, for example.
Here is a complete solution to your question.

```
class BaseClass{
    public obj = [];

    constructor() {
        this.obj.push('1');
        this.obj.push('2');
        this.obj.push('3');
    }

    public todo(): Array<string>{
        return this.obj;
    }
}
class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.obj.push('4');
        this.obj.push('5');
        this.obj.push('6');
    }

    public todo(): Array<string>{
        return this.obj;
    }
}

class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.obj.push('7');
        this.obj.push('8');
        this.obj.push('9');
    }

    public todo(): Array<string>{
        return this.obj;
    }
}

class Test {
    private child1 = new ChildClass1();
    private child2 = new ChildClass2();

    constructor() {
        console.log('child1: ', this.child1.todo());
        console.log('child2: ', this.child2.todo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you described seems pretty straight forward, and calling the base class implementation seems like the simplest solution. The syntax in Typescript is a bit different but the same idea applies:

```
class BaseClass {
    protected obj: string[] = [];
    Todo() {
        this.obj.push("1");
        this.obj.push("2");
        this.obj.push("3");
    }
}
class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass {
    Todo() {
        super.Todo();
        this.obj.push("4");
        this.obj.push("5");
        this.obj.push("6");
    }
}
class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass {
    Todo() {
        super.Todo();
        this.obj.push("7");
        this.obj.push("8");
        this.obj.push("9");
    }
}
var child1 = new ChildClass1();
var child2 = new ChildClass2();
child1.Todo();
child2.Todo();
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of way.